# Using Dirichlet convolution where f = μ ∗ μ (Mobius) to find f(24)?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, mobius-function, dirichlet-convolution

I am confused about the Dirichlet convolution and how it is used. Does it take two entirely different arithmetic functions?

And knowing that f = μ ∗ μ (the Mobius function), why does the question I am solving suggest the Dirichlet convolution formula should be used to solve this, to find f(24)?

Comment: Like ordinary multiplication, the arguments of the Dirichlet convolution may be the same, or may be different.

Comment: *Hint:* (fact) The Dirichlet convolution of multiplicative function is multiplicative. Do you know how to find $f(p^m)$ for primes $p$?

Answer (score 2):

The Dircihlet convolution is defined for $g,h $ (arbitrary) arithmetic functions as 
$$(g \ast h) (n) = \sum_{d\mid n} g(d) h(n/d).$$
It can be thought of as some kind of product of arithmetic functions.

In this sense, yes, it can take entirely different functions $g$ and $h$ and create a new function $g\ast h$; just like you can take two polynomials and form their product. Of course $g=h$ is also possible.

Now, you want to consider $\mu \ast \mu$, and to calculate  $(\mu \ast \mu)(24)$ you have
$$(\mu \ast \mu) (24) = \sum_{d\mid 24} \mu(d) \mu(24/d)$$
and then evaluate the right-hand side explicitly. 
(There may be more clever ways to evaluate this, but in fact it seems you are supposed to do this by this formula.)